# How to convert a String ( ArrayList of HashMap ) to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Here is my code to create a HashMap and ArrayList .

```
HashMap wbsMap = new HashMap();
ArrayList<HashMap<?, String>> list = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<HashMap<?, String>> listChildNew = new ArrayList();
```

Now I have stored the values correspondent to keys like

```
wbsMap.put("COMPONENT_"+i, bom.getString("COMPONENT"));
wbsMap.put("COMP_QTY_"+i, bom.getString("COMP_QTY").replaceAll("\\s+",""));
wbsMap.put("COMP_UNIT_"+i, bom.getString("COMP_UNIT"));
wbsMap.put("NS_LEFT_"+i,String.valueOf(NS_LEFT));
listChildNew=generateBOMStructureLatest(wbsMap,bom.getString("COMPONENT"),NS_RIGHT,String.valueOf(i));
    if(listChildNew.size() >0){
        wbsMap.put("NS_CHILD_"+i,listChildNew);
    }
wbsMap.put("NS_RIGHT_"+i,String.valueOf(NS_LEFT));
list.add(wbsMap);
```

Now the key  `NS_CHILD_` consist of `ArrayList` of `HashMap` that is `listChildNew` . But it get stored in the `wbsMap` `HashMap` as `String` Object. So I am not able to iterate through the `value` for `key` `NS_CHILD_` . How to convert it back to the ArrayList of HashMap.

Here is how the list is coming in log file.

```
[{MATL_DESC_0=Slug for spiral casing, NS_LEFT_0=2, COMP_UNIT_0=PC, NS_RIGHT_0=3, COMP_QTY_0=1, COMPONENT_0=400-110}, 
 {NS_LEFT_1=4, MATL_DESC_1=Flat gasket, COMP_UNIT_1=PC, NS_RIGHT_1=5, COMP_QTY_1=1, COMPONENT_1=400-120}, 
 {MATL_DESC_2=Hexagon head screw M10, COMP_UNIT_2=PC, COMPONENT_2=400-130, NS_LEFT_2=6, NS_RIGHT_2=7, COMP_QTY_2=8}, 
 {COMPONENT_3=400-140, NS_RIGHT_3=15, NS_CHILD_3=[{COMPONENT_3_child=400-141, NS_RIGHT_3_child=10, NS_LEFT_3_child=9, COMP_QTY_3_child=1, MATL_DESC_3_child=Sensor, COMP_UNIT_3_child=PC}, 
                                               {COMPONENT_3_child=400-142, NS_RIGHT_3_child=12, NS_LEFT_3_child=11, COMP_QTY_3_child=1, MATL_DESC_3_child=Display, COMP_UNIT_3_child=PC}, 
                                               {COMPONENT_3_child=400-143, NS_RIGHT_3_child=14, NS_LEFT_3_child=13, COMP_QTY_3_child=1, MATL_DESC_3_child=Casing, COMP_UNIT_3_child=PC}], NS_LEFT_3=8, COMP_QTY_3=1, MATL_DESC_3=Revolution counter, COMP_UNIT_3=PC}, 
{COMPONENT_4=400-150, NS_LEFT_4=16, NS_RIGHT_4=23, NS_CHILD_4=[{NS_LEFT_4_child=17, COMPONENT_4_child=400-151, MATL_DESC_4_child=Temperature sensor, NS_RIGHT_4_child=18, COMP_QTY_4_child=1, COMP_UNIT_4_child=PC}, 
                                                            {NS_LEFT_4_child=19, COMPONENT_4_child=400-152, MATL_DESC_4_child=Display, NS_RIGHT_4_child=20, COMP_QTY_4_child=1, COMP_UNIT_4_child=PC}, 
                                                            {NS_LEFT_4_child=21, COMPONENT_4_child=400-153, MATL_DESC_4_child=Casing, NS_RIGHT_4_child=22, COMP_QTY_4_child=1, COMP_UNIT_4_child=PC}], COMP_QTY_4=1, MATL_DESC_4=Thermostat, COMP_UNIT_4=PC}, 
]
```

Comment: What is `bom` in your code?

Comment: Did u try to define the hashmap generic style?:     HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<?, String>>> wbsMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<?, String>>>();

Comment: bom is  SAP JCO `JCoTable` object `JCoTable bom = tables.getTable("T_STPO");` .

Comment: @WvdL Yes , but I am getting error . `The method put(String, ArrayList<HashMap<?,String>>) in the type HashMap<String,ArrayList<HashMap<?,String>>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)` . Because I have stored String for other keys

Comment: Hm.. what is the error you are getting with your code shown above?

Comment: Would it be an option to make all values of the same type in the hashmap?

Comment: @WvdL I am trying with `HashMap<String,Object> wbsMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();` . Tested the size of `ArrayList` of `HashMap` that is `listChildNew` seems to be working now

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. George has the nicest answer though imo

Comment: check my answer. you need to serialize your arraylist...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to make a tree structure using hashmaps. Try this instead of HashMap.

```
class HashTree {
    private HashMap<String, HashTree> nodes;
    private String value;

    public HashTree(String value){
        this.value = value;
        this.nodes = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public HashTree(HashMap<String,String> nodes){
        this.value = null;
        this.nodes = new HashMap<>();

        for(Entry<String,String> node : nodes){
            this.nodes.put(node.key,node.value);
        }
    }

    public void put(String key, String value){
        nodes.put(key, new HashTree(value));
    }

    public void put(String key, HashMap<String, String> childNodes){
        nodes.put(key, new HashTree(childNodes));
    }

    // Additional getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HashMap is of Type , since you put a key and a value as String in it. When you add an Object it will automatically invoke

> Object.toString()

You have to **serialize** your ArrayList!
This can be achieved with e.g. [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson), where you serialize your ArrayList object into a JSON-String.

Now you could deserialize it into a ArrayList again.